# SQL Column data into Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How do I copy SQL-Server data into an array in c#?
What I want to do is that to retrive the data from SQL-Server and store into an array in c# 
Right now i am having array but its a fixed one i want to copy data from SQL Server in this one.

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hcVendas.YAxis.Add(new YAxisItem { title = new Title("Y") });
        hcVendas.XAxis.Add(new XAxisItem { categories = new[] { "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002" } });

        //New data collection
        var series = new List<Serie>();
        series.Add(new Serie { data = new object[] { 400, 435, 446, 479, 554, 634, 687, 750, 831 } });

        //bind 
        hcVendas.DataSource = series;
        hcVendas.DataBind();


    }
```

Now how to bind data into `new []` and `new object []` from particular column of SQL Server

Comment: What have you got so far? Have you done any kind of data query?

Comment: Well I am able to sort the data from the server that particular column. but dont know how to store it into an array. I have created the datatable but i want a simple c# array

Comment: Yep, share the code, so we can use it to show you how to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , you **don't** need to get all the data to c# and then parse it

Let SQL do the hard work. ( which is merely converting to json string).

For example, you can use  [**this sp(though i'm sure there are other alternatives as well)**](http://karuta.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/gerar-json-em-qualquer-clausula-sql/) which generates `json` string representation :

Example :

[image]

output :

[image]

Now  , when you get this into c# , just pass it to javascript as a ready object.

that's all really.

So - create a `field` :

```
string myJson = GetFromDb();   //Lazy would be great here.(offtopic)
```

And in the client side :

```
var myObj=JSON.parse(<%=myJson %>); //ie8+
//do whatever with myObj....
```

Comment: to be frank I am not aware with json at all. so this example, is it to be executed in the server it self?

Comment: @Saumil The sp does run at the sql server side. but instead of returning raw data (which includes much overhead) to c# - just return the output result of the query which is the json itself. so you wont need json.net or something like that.

Comment: can you guide me to any example which will allow me to learn json from the scratch?

Comment: @Saumil JSON can be considered in many contexts.  : ajax , web services . etc. the whole point is a small structured representation  ( as opposed to XML)of data . just google json  , youll get a lot of stuff. and ofcourse- you can always ask here.

Comment: Database servers is not usually the best place to do xml/json/etc transformations

Comment: @MarcGravell Also sending over the network , extra padded data ( datareader results  which should be digested again at c# side )  - is not the best advice. ( im talking about looking the bytes on the wire. sending the json as a ready result ). and ofcourse - it's all depends. if its a json which its size is huge , he should consider another alternative.

Comment: @RoyiNamir data-reader results will be transmitted as TDS, which is actually pretty terse, and will be far less redundant than JSON (i.e. no duplicated member names, no "20 characters" for a date-time, etc); frankly, if you are going for "bytes on the wire" argument, then raw TDS is going to win every time

Comment: well my ultimate goal is to create chat with respect to time and the particular column value(like 1 days ,1 week).

Comment: @MarcGravell Agreed. (forgot about the repeating columns stuff). just wanted to save him another digest at c#. p.s. I think i've read somewhere about a project that Jon has worked on which is json alike but more terse. do you remember the term ?

Comment: I already have database, so now how do I create json from that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (assuming you have a SqlConnection and SqlCommand object set up):

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
List<string> column_as_list = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    column_as_list.Add(reader.GetString(0));
}
```

Obviously this gets you a list instead of an array. If you desperately need it as an array you probably need to get a count with your select so you know how big to make the array before you loop through.